# machine learning, why do we need to weight data

Tags: machine-learning

This my sound as very naive question. I checked on google and many YouTube videos for beginners and pretty much, all explain data weighting as something the most obvious. I still do not understand why data is being weighted.

Let's assume I have four features:

```
a b c d
1 2 1 4
```

If I pass each value to Sigmond function, I'll receive -1 >< 1 value already.

I really don't understand why data needs or it is recommended to be weighted first. If you could explain to me this in very simple manner, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Describe what you mean by data weighing. Which part of the machine learning pipeline are you seeing this applied?

Comment: I see that feature values before applied to sigmond function are weighted with -1 to 1... actually multiplied. But I don't understand why, why is weight needed in whole process?

Comment: If your data values are always large positive numbers, what is the value of the sigmoid (not sigmond) function using those inputs?

Comment: i really don't understand. We weight data to get negative values?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not talking about weighing data but features.
A feature is a column in your table and as data I would understand rows.

The confusion comes now from the fact that weighing rows is also sometimes sensible, e.g., if you want to punish misclassification of positive class more.

Why do we need to weigh features?
I assume you are talking about a modle like

```
 prediction = sigmoid(sum_i weight_i * feature_i) > base
```

Let's assume you want to predict whether a person is overweight based on Bodyweight, height, and age.

In R we can generate a sample dataset as

```
height = rnorm(100,1.80,0.1) #normal distributed mean 1.8,variance 0.1
weight = rnorm(100,70,10)
age = runif(100,0,100)
ow = weight / (height**2)>25 #overweight if BMI > 25
data = data.frame(height,weight,age,bc,ow)
```

if we now plot the data you can see that at least my sample of the data can be separated with a straight line in weight/height. However, age does not provide any value. If we weight it prior to the sum/sigmoid you can put all factors into relation.

[image]

Furthermore, as you can see from the following plot the weight/height have a very different domain. Hence, they need to be put into relation, such that the line in the following plot has the right slope, as the value of weight have are one order of magnitude larger

[image]